# Ajax call issue with https site

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

Hi Friends, 
                 I have a Ajax call in MVC application which makes call to action as below.

```
$.ajax({
                    url: '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppUrl"].ToString()%>/Account/CustomerRegister',
                    type: "GET",
                    data: {
                        name: cname, //these valus are retreived from text controller
                        email: cemail,
                        phone: cphone,
                        msg: cmsg
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result.Status == "success") {
                            window.location = "welcome.aspx";
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#msgsuccess").text("There was an error while submitting your query. Please try again.");
                            $("#msgsuccess").addClass("red");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (da) {
                        $("#msgsuccess").text("There was an error while submitting your query. Please try again.");
                        $("#msgsuccess").addClass("red");
                    }
                });
```

The issue I am facing here is when the url points to SSL configured site, the ajax method always end up in error, where as no exception occur in action method and the register user and send mail functioanlity  is achieved successfully.

Concer here is when the url is configured to non SSL (same site) it works perfectly but when the site is configured to SSL it result in error : function, I spent some time on googling but couldn't find solution any suggestion or help on this would be appreciated.

below is my action method.

```
 [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult CustomerRegister(string name, string email, string phone, string msg)
        {
            try
            {
                //add customer fucnionaltiy

                //Send email to customerSupport.

                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("Dear" + name );
                sb.Append("\n\t\t\t\t registration is done............ ");
                sb.Append("\n WebMaster.");
                util.SendEmail(email, "Customer Register", sb.ToString(), false);

                 return Json(new {Status = "success"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet );
            } catch {

                return Json(new { Status = "Invalid" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```

Comment: What is the error code returned by the ajax call ?

Comment: There is nothing as such, the Ajax call straight away get into the a error: function (da) {} with da as null.

Comment: In the error callback, the first parameter (da in your case) is a superset of the xmlHTTPrequest then it should not be null. Did you try to diagnostics this with a tool like firebug or chrome web tools ? If you're using jquery 1.5+ you could also take advantage of the deferred object returned from the $.ajax() : `var ajax = $.ajax({ ... }); ajax.fail(function (jqXHr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    $("#error").html(jqXHr.responseText);
});`

Answer (score 0):

I got a 400 BAD REQUEST when upgrading my ajax calls from http to https.

In my case a special charachter 'é' caused problems when ajax call was made over HTTPS.

you probably need to encode all special characters.